# Incrementar una misma posición si se cumple los tres valores anteriores de una fila en Sql server

Tags: sql-server

Cordial saludo, espero se encuentren bien quiero pedirles un favor en soporte con lo siguiente requerimiento, tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
use alumnotas
select ROW_NUMBER()over (order by Oro desc)idpais, Pais, Oro, Plata, Bronce, Oro+Plata+Bronce as Total from olimpicos1 order by Oro desc, 
Plata desc, Bronce desc;
```

Cuyo resultado es el siguiente:

> Cuando el Oro, Plata y Bronce, sea igual al anterior registro, me incremente en uno solo el valor de la posición, es decir que compartan la misma posición:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo primero que debes determinar en que momento se hará la inserción cuando se agregue un nuevo registro manualmente? o mediante un trigger, si el caso es manualmente es sencillo, solo debes leer el ultimo registro antes de realizar la inserción y en base a esa lectura puedes realizar la inserción la otra opción es un poco mas complicada pero te ahorra código, solo debes crear un trigger que se gatille `BEFORE_INSERT()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias muy amable por su colaboración.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo necesitas cambiar la función a RANK().

```
select RANK() OVERT(ORDER BY Oro DESC, Plata DESC, Bronce DESC) AS idpais, 
    Pais, 
    Oro, 
    Plata, 
    Bronce, 
    Oro + Plata + Bronce AS Total 
FROM olimpicos1 
ORDER BY idpais DESC;
```

Comment: Desde Bogotá D.C, Colombia un Abrazo don Luis Cazares, ese era el inconveniente que se me presentaba y diste con la solución de lo que necesitaba, todas las bendiciones!.

Comment: Si te ha servido la solución, márcala como aceptada para que les sirva a otros usuarios.